# Upgrade from Server 16 to 18.04 LTS breaks Samba shares from XP machines

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, samba, windows-xp

I have had Samba working for years with Server version 16.  This morning, I upgraded to 18.04 LTS, and Windows XP now gets

System error 1326 has occurred.

Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

I have always had Samba configured to us pam to sync with system passwords.  I also ran smbpasswd manually, but it did not help.

Active lines of smb.conf:

```
[global]



  workgroup = RHFACTOR

   dns proxy = no

   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

   max log size = 1000

   syslog = 0

   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

   server role = standalone server

   passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

   unix password sync = yes

   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u

   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:*%n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

   pam password change = yes

   map to guest = bad user

   usershare max shares = 10

   usershare allow guests = no

[share0]

  comment = share0 zero

  path = /winbackup/zero

  browsable = yes

  guest ok = no

  read only = no

  create mask = 0755
```

(Three more shares identical to above, except for share name and directory.

I reviewed the Samba and AppArmor sections of the 18.04 manual.  I tried disabling AppArmor and restarting Samba, but it made no difference.

Comment: Are you sure the samba on XP is compatible with the versions 18.04 uses?

Comment: Check the manual. Less secure version of Samba may be disabled by default in the newer release. It can probably be re-enabled.

Comment: Moribus1 nailed it with the lanman auth and ntlm auth parameters.  Ken Sharp, there is no mention of more or less secure versions in the Ubutu manual's Samba chapter.  The Samba manual I could find was mighty ugly, and I had no idea about security levels at the time

Comment: If you are so inclined please mark my answer below as "accepted": https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers We win prizes based on the number of correct answers. At least I think we do - maybe not.

Comment: @Morbius1 I got a mail from the head honcho of Stack and a ton of swag (heck I was allowed to pick it myself) when I won the 100k rep race ;-)  +1 on the answer from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Samba is doing its best to keep up with the Win10s and macOSs of the world so it has moved on.

Add these lines in the [global] section of smb.conf:

```
lanman auth = yes
ntlm auth = yes
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Note: I remember coming across a situation where you actually had to degrade the max server smb dialect used in addition to the lines above:

```
server max protocol = NT1
```

That would be a travesty. I don't know how a Win10 machine would ever be able to connect to it.

Comment: Great.  How did you know this was the way to go?

Comment: DIdn't work for me. The last thing I was expecting was to have to reinstall 16.04 on my file server. Ubuntu have really taken a big step backwards with the 18.04 release. I shudder when I realise that this is the LTS release. It's bad on so many other levels.

Answer (score 0):

I have not repulation enough to comment, @Morbius1's answer is working. If for some reason it doesn't work for you, then consider using smbpasswd. Steps:
1. Install Ubuntu 18
2. `sudo apt install samba`
3. add comment Morbius1's answer to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. Then modify [homes] whatever info to share 
4. `sudo smbpasswd -a allkkang`
5. `sudo systemctl restart smbd`