# Can't access samba share from Windows 2003

Tags: server, windows, samba

I have upgraded Ubuntu to the latest 18.04 LTS and recreated share that was on it before, a simple share.

```
comment = share folder
browseable = yes
path = /home/user/share
guest ok = no 
create mask = 0664 
directory mask = 0775
valid users = @share
read only = no
force user = user
```

and now I can access it from win 7, 2008, 2012 etc but can't from win 2003. I see the share but it just won't accept credentials and I can't access it.

Comment: This sounds like a protocol version issue. Have a look at what versions are enabled by default, I bet you will have to enable an old version manually

Comment: Since Win2003 is roughly equivalent to WinXP on the desktop perhaps this answer will also fox yours: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066035/upgrade-from-server-16-to-18-04-lts-breaks-samba-shares-from-xp-machines/1066049#1066049